# NumberFormatException error; string to int conversion

Tags: string-conversion

I tried converting a string "A1+B2" to an integer because A1 and A2 are both integers but it doesn't evaluate the sum. Any idea how I could solve this problem?

Comment: First thing please use appropriate tag then onlywe wil come to know in language you are try to work out and if it is in java please post the code you tried for conversion

Comment: Unless you are considering hexadecimal or a different numbering system with a base greater than 10, or an alternative encoding of digits, you will have to explain more about exactly how `A1` and `B2` are integers. But I would think looking up (or computing) the value of `A1` and the value of `A2`, adding them together, and returning that sum would be the way to go...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the javadoc of Integer.parseInt (String).
It clearly states that the parameter to this method must be a numeric value, if not it will throw NumberFormatException. In your case, you are providing an unevaluated expression which is not a numeric value yet.